# pear / Services_W3C_HTMLValidator Error?

Tags: php, pear, w3c-validation

I have installed this package on many of servers but we now have an in house ubuntu server we are trying to install this package on.  We have pear installed and installed this package as it does show all the files located in usr/share/php/Services/W3C/ However when we run the following code.

```
require_once ('Services/W3C/HTMLValidator.php');
```

We recieve the following error.

```
Warning: require_once(Services/W3C/HTMLValidator.php): failed to open stream: No such 
file or directory in /var/www/test.php on line 4 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed
opening required 'Services/W3C/HTMLValidator.php'
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/pear') 
in /var/www/test.php on line 4
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this error.

EDIT:  After closer testing I found that I am unable to include anything from the include paths such as HTTP/Request2.php is not available either.

I am currently searching to find if there may be a php setting or restriction preventing this but I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Probably the generic description of the error sheds some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12820243#12820243

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your [include_path](http://php.net/include_path) correctly. Have a look at [this section](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php) in the PEAR installation manual.